# SQL Comparing 2 dates and displaying in table if >3 days

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

In my table I have a couple date fields and when i run my query I want to compare the reschedule date(frsdt) against the Due date(frdte) and only show records if they are > 3 days. I pulling my hair out for a few days thought I would reach out for help. any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT fprod
    ,pord
    ,desc
    ,CASE 
    WHEN ftype = 'P' 
      THEN 'Planned' 
    ELSE 'Firm' 
    END
    ,vndnam
    ,fppvnd
    ,fqty
    ,DATE(TO_DATE(RTRIM(CHAR(fdate))
    ,DATE(TO_DATE(RTRIM(CHAR(frdte))
    ,DATE(TO_DATE(RTRIM(CHAR(frsdt))
    ,pecst * pqord
FROM avm
    ,kfp
    ,iiml01
    ,hpo 
INTO 
    :tblPAM.colItmNbr
    ,:tblPAM.colPONbr
    ,:tblPAM.colDesc
    ,:tblPAM.colType
    ,:tblPAM.colVendor
    ,:tblPAM.colVendorId
    ,:tblPAM.colQty
    ,:tblPAM.colRelDate
    ,:tblPAM.colDueDate
    ,:tblPAM.colRescDate
    ,:tblPAM.colPOAmount 
WHERE vendor = fppvnd 
    AND fprod = iprod 
    AND year(frsdt) < 9999 
    AND pldte > pddte + 3 days
    AND month(frsdt)|| '/' || day(frsdt) || '/' || year(frsdt) > month(frdte)|| '/' || day(frdte)  || '/' || year(frdte)
```

[image]

## Query rewrite recommended to start with

```
SELECT T.*
FROM
(
SELECT fprod
    ,pord
    ,desc
    ,CASE 
    WHEN ftype = 'P' 
      THEN 'Planned' 
    ELSE 'Firm' 
    END some_alias1
    ,vndnam
    ,fppvnd
    ,fqty
    ,DATE(TO_DATE(RTRIM(CHAR(fdate)) fdate_alias
    ,DATE(TO_DATE(RTRIM(CHAR(frdte)) frdte_alias
    ,DATE(TO_DATE(RTRIM(CHAR(frsdt)) frsdt_alias
    ,pecst * pqord some_alias2
FROM avm
    ,kfp
    ,iiml01
    ,hpo 
WHERE vendor = fppvnd 
    AND fprod = iprod
) T 
WHERE year(frsdt_alias) < 9999 
  AND pldte_alias > pddte_alias + 3 days
  AND frsdt_alias > frdte_alias;
```

Comment: Which format of SQL are you using?

Comment: Date functions are _very_ product specific. Please tag your question with the specific database that you're using. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: I am using  Db2® for IBM® i database. I am new to programming so i am not sure if that what you needed to know. Sorry

Comment: Try `date1 > date2 + 3 day`. `date1` & `date2` must be of `date` or `timestamp` data type.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein -- I think it is `+ 3 DAYS`,  won't work if you use `DAY`

Comment: @Hogan It must work. Refer to the [Labeled durations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzdtdur.htm) link.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein -- good point I was guessing that was a problem because he was getting an error.   Apparently he is using a number instead of a date field for mysterious reason

Comment: I was handed this project that has been this way for 10 years with alot of data. So changing to date field is not an option right now.

Comment: I updated above based on Marks post and i still get a DB2/400 SQL:-187[IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0187 - Use of labeled duration not valid.  (the 3 days my guess) my guess because I am using decimal over date.

Comment: @MikeOffenbecher -- when you are handed a project you often have to refactor it.  My suggestion, create a new date column and run the conversion once as outlined in mark's answer.  Then you will have real date columns and everything is easier.  Just because the last guy wanted to work with screwed up data does not mean you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a very basic example on how to convert your numeric date representation to date and how to do basic math on dates. Consider `MYTAB` "virtual" table here as your table containing 2 numeric columns.
Run it as is.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    DATE(TO_DATE(RTRIM(CHAR(D1)), 'YYYYMMDD')) DAT1
  , DATE(TO_DATE(RTRIM(CHAR(D2)), 'YYYYMMDD')) DAT2
  FROM
  (
  VALUES 
    (20181004, 20181007)
  , (20181004, 20181017)
  ) MYTAB (D1, D2)
) T
WHERE DAT2 > DAT1 + 3 DAY;
```

The result is:

```
|DAT1        |DAT2        |
|------------|------------|
|2018-10-04  |2018-10-17  |
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for the response. Let me give this a look over. I really appreciate the help from both of you.

Comment: I am curious Mark. How does it in your where statement still not read the D1 and D2 as decimal data type?

Comment: I used the same aliases `Dx` for columns with `DATE(TO_DATE(RTRIM(CHAR(Dx)), 'YYYYMMDD'))` expressions. These columns have `DATE` data type afterwards. I've updated the example for easier understanding.

Comment: The reason I provided my example in such a form is, that it may run as is. Imagine, that you have a table `MYTAB` with 2 numeric columns D1 and D2. The `FROM (VALUES ...) MYTAB (D1, D2)` clause would change to `FROM MYTAB` in this case. What I do here is forming a "temporary" results set with 2 date columns first using subselect (their aliases are DAT1 and DAT2), where each column is a result of expression. It's convenient to use such a temporary result set, since I don't have to writhe the same long expression multiple times used multiple times further.

Comment: So once you convert the data type from decimal to date, does it remember that while reading through the rest of the query?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. These are SQL basics, which you should be familiar with. I'd suggest you to start with such a working example and try to adapt it to your case with small steps by steps...

Comment: @MarkBarinstein-- it was not my question.  But thanks for thinking of me :D

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Thanks i will check it out later, I am on the road atm, Thanks for all your help today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date arithmatic to solve this.

For example in SQL Server it would look like this:

```
WHERE dateadd(day,3, frsdt) >= frdte
```

In DB2 it would look like this

```
WHERE frsdt + 3 DAYS >= frdte
```

Here I add 3 days to the first date.  If it is greater than the target date then I know they are less than 3 days apart.

If I wanted to know if the dates were greater than 3 days apart I would do this instead

```
WHERE dateadd(day,3, frsdt) < frdte
```

> The function for adding dates will change depending on the platform you are using -- but the basic idea follows what I show above.  Add 3 days to the date and then do your compare in the WHERE statement.

Comment: Hogan thanks for the response. I have tried this and I always get the following error. DB2/400 SQL:-206[IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0206 - Column or global variable DAY not found.

Comment: Anyone know why I would get this error. Column or global variable DAY not found

Comment: @MikeOffenbecher you didn't show the db2 code that gave an error, but I put an example above -- if you still get an error show me what your code is.

Comment: so when i use "WHERE frsdt + 3 DAYS >= frdte"  I get  Use of labeled duration not valid.  I am sure its because the columns in the DB are decimal and not date. So as you can see I am converting them to a date(so to speak) in my query. The table was set up a long time ago and I am trying to work with what I have as there is a lot of data in it.

Comment: I posted the updated code in the original post above.

Comment: yes it needs to be a date type before it will work -- so you have to convert to a date and then do date math.  you are converting to date -- you are just printing it out.

Comment: So you are saying the only way to do this is to change the data type in the table to a date field?

Comment: actually that does not make sense... you can use the MONTH DAY AND YEAR funcitons on them that means it is stored as a date or timestamp.  are month day and year working?  are those custom functions?  how exactly are you storing this data?

Comment: The date is being store as a decimal data type in the database  for example(20,181,004 )  I can pull the data and manipulate it enough in the query to show it as a true date but cant do any date logic to it.

Comment: ok, 20181004 -- what date is that september 4th 2018 or april 10th 2018?

Comment: It does not matter -- DB2 has a function called TO_DATE -- you should be able to use that to make a DATE type result... then when you have the DATE type my code above will work.

Comment: that is september 4th 2018

Comment: you could do `WHERE frsdt + 3 DAYS >= frdte` and it would be right most of the time -- except when the month or year would change in 3 days.

Comment: Hogan thanks for the help. Even with using the to_date function it gives back the same error. Maybe it just cant be done as a decimal data type.

Comment: how are you calling the to_date function?

Comment: Hogan, I edit the original to show how i used the to_date